# How to include inner project with gradle builder

Tags: java, gradle

I try to follow some tutorial and create my own Gradle task and I need to create the inner project for it. I created a new directory in my main folder with the same structure:

```
mainproject
--> src
------>build.gradle
------>main
----------->java
--------------->MainJavaClass.java
----->innerproject
---------> src
-------------> build.gradle
------------->main
----------------->java
-------------------->InnerJavaClass.java
```

But in this case I can't use any dependencies in `innerproject` and `InnerJavaClass.java`, and even can't execute `psvm` method from the `InnerJavaClass`.
The error:

- Could not find or load main class `InnerJavaClass.java`

How to correctly include the inner project?

Comment: You should look into using multi module projects

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use Multi module projects.
here is a simple example.

`Project A` (main) and includes `Project B` and `Project C`.

`Project A` setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'A'
include ':B', ':C'
```

And `Project A` build.gradle dependency section

```
implementation project(':B')
implementation project(':C')
```

`Project B` and `Project C` are the same with no extra information and here is an example

Project B setting.gradle

```
rootProject.name = 'B'
```

And defualt build.gradle with no extra information required.

The structure should be look something like the following

```
A
--> build.gradle
--> setting.gradle
--> src
------>main
----------->java
--------------->MainJavaClass.java
-->B
--> build.gradle (for B)
--> setting.gradle (for B)
--> src
------>main
----------->java
--------------->MainJavaClass.java (for B)
-->C
--> build.gradle (for C)
--> setting.gradle (for C)
--> src
------>main
----------->java
--------------->MainJavaClass.java (for C)
```

This way you can use the dependencies and once you build `A project` both `B` and `C` would be build as included dependency.

Comment: I see you placed all projects parallelly in the graph. Does it a mistake? I expected the main project should be root for descendants

Comment: Yes, It's a mistake, and your right about it.